# Flexbox float right

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I am looking for solutions on Flexbox layout best practice for a common use case.

[image: example]

In the example, I want to use Flexbox to make the score number to be float to the right. I thought of using:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

But then the problem is that we can't use the center align with the outer box.

Another way I can think of is to make another flex box to wrap the image and name part, then create an outer flex box to use

```
justifyContent: space-between;
```

to make the expected layout.

Comment: Consider flex `auto` margins: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Comment: I found `position: absolute; right 0;` still very useful when "floating" something to the right that should span over multiple other flex-item "rows" that should not be affected by the item pinned to the right. Using 'float: right;' in chrome somehow affects other flex-contents that follow afterwards (they won't take up the space occupied by the right-floated content). They need to be converted to `display: block` to take up the space correctly, but I'm more happy using absolute positioning in that particular case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `justify-content: space-between` it will push elements to the sides:

```css
.flex {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.one {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
}

.two {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
}

.three {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px; height: 20px;
}
```

```html
Growing middle element
<div class="flex">
  <div class="one"></div><div class="two flex-grow"></div><div class="three"></div>
</div>

Without growing element
<div class="flex">
  <div class="one"></div><div class="two"></div><div class="three"></div>
</div>

Without middle element
<div class="flex">
  <div class="one"></div><div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Refer to this amazing  tutorial to easily understand how flex box behaves: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This answer works a lot better than @pradeep1991singh answer.  `margin-left:auto` will cause unexpected results in a lot of places.

Answer (score 104):

This will help you

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child2 {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">left</div>
  <div class="child2">right</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Will this solution work with 3 children? Lets say 2 on right on 1 on left.

Comment: @John it does work with 3 children

Comment: "For Bootstrap-5 we have to use ms-auto instead of ml-auto", source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65562241/1956540

Answer (score 10):

Use this awesome guide to answer common Flexbox questions: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

Pseudocode:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <ProfilePicture />
  <Text style={{flex: 1}}>{username}</Text>
  <ScoreNumber />
</View>
```

This renders the 3 elements next to each other, with the `Text` occupying all the available space, therefore pushing the `ScoreNumber` to the right.

Comment: What is the shorthand `flex: 1` mean? Is this the same as `flex-grow: 1`?

Comment: A bit late but yes, it's the shorthand for `flex-grow: 1`. It can be extended as `flex: none | [ <'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'>? || <'flex-basis'> ]`.

Comment: it doesn't work if you remove middle element. `justify-content: space-between` should be used to achieve that instead.